# Hay alguna forma de obtener solo los números sin repetir de una lista en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo estos datos, ¿hay algún comando que me facilite solo contar los números que no se repitan? y obtener la posición donde se encuentran en la lista. gracias de antemano.

Lista: [2, 5, 6, 6, 11, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]

Comment: [Distinct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Para la otra pregunta dentro de la pregunta, *". . . obtener la posición donde se encuentra en la lista"* No existe algo así. Tendrás que implementarlo tú solo. Por cierto... Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

En la programación, la estructura de datos HashSet permite el uso de datos sin repetirse.

En la documentación oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0 se muestra los detalles a tener en cuenta.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        List<int> lista = new List<int> { 2, 5, 6, 6, 11, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 };
        var listaSinRepetidos = new HashSet<int>(lista);
        foreach(var item in listaSinRepetidos){
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Genera como resultado:

```
2
5
6
11
1
3
```

Comment: Aunque se puede utilizar `HashSet`, me pregunto si en realidad es la mejor herramienta para este caso. OP quiere **eliminar duplicados**; esa es su *intención*. Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298679/whats-better-for-creating-distinct-data-structures-hashset-or-linqs-distinct) de SO en inglés me parece muy interesante, e ilustra la importancia de la 'intención'

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. El título: `Hay alguna forma de obtener solo los números sin repetir de una lista en C#`, da una idea general, quiere hacer un filtrado. 2. `¿hay algún comando que me facilite solo contar los números que no se repitan? ` Siguiendo la secuencia del título, se reitera la idea del filtro de números únicos. 3. `y obtener la posición donde se encuentran en la lista` Aquí nada agregué, la pregunta está relativamente acertada con la `intención`, y como carece de intentos, el haber puesto una alternativa a la otra respuesta, me parece bien. Programador que NO intenta, NO crece, ¿verdad?

Comment: Supongo... También podría enviar los números a un procedimiento almacenado en Azure CosmosDB que tome una lista de enteros como parámetro y luego haga un `SELECT DISTINCT` y envíe la respuesta a través de SignalR... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   En fin...

Comment: ¿O.o? Creo que te faltó mandar una señal desde algún dispositivo IoT para que inicie el proceso hahahaha xD!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Como te dijo Arriel podes usar el metodo que es parte de Linq ***.Distinct()***
que te va a devolver una lista nueva con valores sin repetir

```
List<int> lista = new List<int> { 2, 5, 6, 6, 11, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 };

var listaDistinct = lista.Distinct();

foreach (int num in listaDistinct)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

para usarla no olvides importar

```
using System.Linq;
```